# How to retrieve data from entity with composed foreign key?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, entity

I can't retrieve data from an Entity from my Oracle database.

Config :

- Java 8
- Hibernate 5.4.20
- Jpa 2.2
- Oracle11g

My situation :

A JPA Entity Reparation with "classic" data, and an ID from a Vehicule.
A JPA Entity Vehicule stored without a unique ID column because in my table, each vehicule has a period (identify by startDate and endDate) with unique properties.

Example :

| id | situation | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN_USINE | 01/01/2020 | 14/01/2020 |
| 1 | TRANSFERT | 15/01/2020 | 17/01/2020 |
| 1 | EN_CONCESSION | 18/01/2020 | 01/03/2020 |

The primary key of Vehicule is defined by 3 columns : id/startDate/endDate.

I want to get data from Vehicule in the entity Reparation, i got the id of the Vehicule in the table Raparation, and the jointure is done with the date of Reparation that has to be between startDate and endDate in the table Vehicule.
How can i do that ?

```
@Entity
Public class Vehicule {
    @Column(name="id")
    String id
    
    @Column(name="startDate")
    LocalDate startDate
    
    @Column(name="endDate")
    LocalDate endDate
}
```

```
@Entity
Public class Reparation {
    
    @Column(name="id_reparation")
    String idReparation
    
    @Column(name="date_of_reparation")
    LocalDate dateOfReparation
    
    Vehicule vehicule 
}
```

I tried the @joinFormula, but I didn't get it

How would you do that ?

Edit :
I tried a lot of things, like :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "select id from table_vehicule", referencedColumnName = "ID")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "select startDate from table_vehicule where dateOfReparation > startDate", referencedColumnName = "startDate")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "select endDate from table_vehicule where dateOfReparation < endDate", referencedColumnName = "endDate"))
})
Vehicule vehicule;
```

Comment: show us what JoinFormula you've tried

Comment: I edited my post to put what i tried

Comment: This construct is new for me, too, but id suggest:
for id you could use @JoinColumn, and the formulas can't work, since they can return multiply values. You could try: `SELECT max(startDate) from table_vehicule where dateOfReparation > startDate`. and min(endDate) in the other formula

Answer (score 0):

First thing is ,you can't have an @Entity without providing any @Id to that class ,second if you have an ID composed of multiple fields ,like in your case here ,you make it Embeddable ,and then you declare it in your class as a class member ,here's an example :

```
@Embeddable 
public class MyComposedID {
 
//Here ,I personaly don't see the usage of id it's neither a surrogate key nor
//used to have any impact on the uniqueness of the Composed Id since you said 
//it's uniquely identified by the start and end date
 @Column(name="id")
 String id;
 @Column(name="start_date")
 LocalDate startDate;

 @Column(name="end_date")
 LocalDate endDate;
 
}
```

Now you declare it in your Vehicle Entity as an EmbeddedID as follows :

```
@Entity
Public class Vehicule {

 @EmbeddedId
 MyComposedID id;

}
```

As for the query goes , from what i understood ,you want to get the vehicle where the Reparation.reparationDate is between the Vehicle.startDate and Vehicle.endDate,
here's an example with a JPQL query :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicle v "+
       "INNER JOIN Reparation r ON r.reparationDate>= v.id.startDate "+
       "AND r.reparationDate<=v.id.endDate");
```

Hope this helps you .